# Swift segmented contorl show/hide cells in uicollectionview depending on firebase logic

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm having a hard time trying to display/hide my collectionview cells depending on the items child nodes in FB realtime database. The problem consists of three parts: FB database, a collectionview and a segmented control. My goal is to show different cells in the collectionview depending on whether a the item has a child with a certain string value.

**My database looks like this:**

```
Items
   category1
      item1
         name: item1
         imageUrl: item1Url
         logic
            one
            three
      item2
         name: item1
         imageUrl: item1Url
         logic
            two
            three
   category2
      item1
         name: item1
         imageUrl: item1Url
         logic
            two
            four
      item2
         name: item1
         imageUrl: item1Url
         logic
            one
            two
```

**I also have a custom Product class to display my items in their cells:**

```
class Product {
    var category: String?
    var name: String?
    var imageUrl: String?

    init(rawData: [String: AnyObject]) {
        name = rawData["name"] as? String
        imageUrl = rawData["imageUrl"] as? String
        category = rawData["category"] as? String
    }
}
```

**I load my items from firebase database with this funciton:**

```
func loadCategoryName() {
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("Items").child(selectedCategoryFromPreviousVC)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            self.itemArray = []
            let rawValues = Array(data.values)
            for item in rawValues {
                let product = Product(rawData: item as! [String: AnyObject])
                product.category = self.selectedCategoryFromPreviousVC
                self.itemArray.append(product)
            }

            // Sort item array by rating; if rating is same, sort by name
            self.itemArray.sort { (s1, s2) -> Bool in
                if s1.rating == s2.rating {
                    return s1.name! < s2.name!
                } else {
                    return s1.rating > s2.rating
                }
            }
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

**My itemArray now contains all my items as custom Products and I can display them in their cell.**

***My segmented control:***

```
func someFunc() {
    let segmentController = UISegmentedControl(items: ["one", "two", "three", "four"])

    segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentController
    segmentController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSegment), for: .valueChanged)
}

@objc fileprivate func handleSegment() {
    print(segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex)
}
```

with the handleSegment function I'm able to print out which segment has been selected. But this is where the problems occur. I've tried creating new arrays to split the items so that items are in an array depending on their "logic" child nodes. However I'm not able to make the arrays of type Product, so that I can use them to repopulate the collectionview. Also I'm not really sure what the best way of storing the logic part in my database would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extend your Product class:

```
class Product {
   ...
   let logic: [String]?

   init(...) {
      ...
      logic = rawData["logic"] as? [String]
   }
}
```

In your CollectionViewDataSource add some variables to store current state

```
var products: [Products]
var filteredProducts: [Product]
var currentFilter: String? {
   didSet {
      guard let currentFilter = currentFilter else {
         filteredProducts = products
         return
      }
      filteredProducts = products.filter { product in
         return product.logic.contains(currentFilter)
      }
   }
}
```

extend your handleSegment func:

```
@objc fileprivate func handleSegment() {
   print(segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex)
   currentFilter = segmentController.titleForSegment(at: segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex)
   collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

In your collectionView datasource, use filteredProducts to build the cells.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Robin, the filteredProducts array and currentFilter variables were the ones I was having a though time understanding how to do! In the handleSegment function I had to change the currentFilter to segmentController.titleForSegment(at: segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex) but now it works perfectly.

Comment: I still have one question though: I don't really understand how I'm suposed to store my "logic" node under the items in the database. Now I've simply put "logic" as the key and either one, two, three or four as the value at each item. This works, but this way each item only gets one value that it shows up for, and I'd like multiple. The only solution I see is to save the numbers as children of the logic node and just assign a random key like item1 -> logic -> one: yes, three: yes, but this seems a little cumbersome?

Comment: Great that you figured it out! :)  To store you logic node, just add an array of type String for key "logic" (as I did in Products model). This way, your models should be represented in local database exact as in firebase

Comment: I know you can easily do this by selecting “array” when using firestore, but I can’t find any way to do this when using db as I’m not able to save values under a child without them both having a key and a value (which makes it a dictionary instead of an array)

Comment: What type of db do you use locally? Do you use CoraData?

Comment: I’m planning on updating the items in my app with so I’m only relying on Firebase real-time database to display data in my cells so far. I don’t have a local database yet, would I need this?

Comment: Ah ok, then it seems I misunderstood your problem with db. I thought, the data structure you showed in your post would be the structure you have setup in firebase ..

Comment: In Realtime DB, you can just add a field `logic` with value `["one", "two", "three"]` and it will be mapped as array. In FB DB it is presented with 0: "one", 1: "two"... but in JSON it is a normal array without index